# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains

Tags: spring, spring-security

this is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>



 <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="student_dao" class="com.dao.User_dao_imp"/>
<bean id="student_service" class="com.service.User_service_imp"/>
<bean id="product_dao" class="com.dao.Product_dao_impl"/>
<bean id="product_service" class="com.service.Product_service_impl"/>

<bean id="userdetail" class="com.controller.UserDetail" />


<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
 <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/config/messages"/>
 <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>         
</bean>



<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />



 </beans>
```

this is my security.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/add_role.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<form-login login-page="/login.htm"/>
<logout logout-url="/logout"/>
 </http>


<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userdetail">
    <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

After debugging i am getting error

SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userdetail' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userdetail' is defined

Answer (score 0):

Define your `userdetail` bean in `security.xml` configuration, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/add_role.htm" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<form-login login-page="/login.htm"/>
<logout logout-url="/logout"/>
 </http>


<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userdetail">
    <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userdetail" class="com.controller.UserDetail" />
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: it is defined, problem in something else

Comment: I know you defined it in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` but somehow spring container could not recognize it. copy `userdetail` bean definition from `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `security.xml`.

Comment: Have a closer look at stacktrace: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userdetail' is defined`